# jQuery - Check if a group of Check Boxes are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How do I check if any of the Check Boxes in chkInv* (chkInv1 and chkInv2) are checked and exclude chkUnrelated.

```
<label for="chkInv2-0">
  <input name="chkInv2" id="chkInv2-0" type="checkbox" value="1">
  chkInv2
</label>

<label for="chkInv2-1">
  <input name="chkInv2" id="chkInv2-1" type="checkbox" value="2">
  chkInv2
</label>

<label for="chkInv3-0">
  <input name="chkInv3" id="chkInv3-0" type="checkbox" value="3">
  chkInv3
</label>

<label for="chkInv3-1">
  <input name="chkInv3" id="chkInv3-1" type="checkbox" value="4">
  chkInv3
</label>

<label for="chkUnrelated">
  <input name="chkUnrelated" id="chkUnrelated-1" type="checkbox" value="4">
  chkUnrelated
</label>
```

My current code checks all the Check Boxes of the page.

`var checkBoxes = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;`

Can I use some kind of regular expression?

`var checkBoxes = $('input:checkbox[name=chkInv*]:checked').length;`

Comment: `[name^=chkInv]` matches names that begin with `chkInv`. All the jQuery attribute selectors are listed here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: You could also use `:not([name=chkUnrelated])`.

Comment: `var ischecked = $('input[name^=chkInv]').is(':checked');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you `checkboxes` without `chkUnrelated`

```
var checkBoxes = $(':checkbox[name^=chkInv]');
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

To check any of the checkbox is checked, use the following

```
if($('input[name^="chkInv"]:checked').length > 0) {
           //Code goes here
}
```

This will automatically exclude the checkbox with name `chkUnrelated`